# Rebuilding sql server indexes speeds up WCF response time

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I have a simple WCF (IIS hosted) that sends XML payload to the database (SQL server) and returns the result set.

The average response time for a particular service is 12 sec where it should be 1 or 2 sec's. However, when i am rebuilding the indexes associated to the table, that the service brings the data from, the response time is falling to 1 or 2 secs and going back to 12 secs after some time.

Why is this happening ? Should i setup a rebuild index job for every 2 or 3 hrs ?

Comment: What is the query you are sending via xml?

Comment: I'm sending the XML payload to the stored proc, reading it through sp_xml_preparedocument and querying the input from the xml.

Comment: are you building index online??

Comment: Can You elaborate on how you are rebuilding the indexes?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by adding WITH RECOMPILE at the beginning of the procedure and calling EXEC sp_xml_removedocument at the end of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All.

I was able to resolve this issue by adding WITH RECOMPILE at the beginning of the procedure and calling EXEC sp_xml_removedocument at the end of the procedure.